# Show that any open subsets of the real line are $F_\sigma$-sets.

Tags: general-topology

This is an exercise from a topological book. It is this:

> Show that any open subsets of the real line are $F_\sigma$-sets.

Could anybody help to solve it?

Comment: You could do it for metric spaces in general. Let $F$ be a non-empty closed set, then $x \mapsto d(x,F)$ is a continuous function vanishing exactly on $F$. It follows that $F$ is a $G_\delta$, being the intersection of countably many open sets: $F = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{x\,:\,d(x,F) \lt 1/n\}$. Thus $F^c$ is an $F_\sigma$.

Comment: @t.b. Very nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that open subsets of the real line are countable unions of (pairwise disjoint) open intervals.  Next show that every open interval is an F$_\sigma$-set.  As countable unions of F$_\sigma$-sets are also F$_\sigma$, this gives the result.

Comment: My idea is this: for an open interval $[a,b]$, there are countably open intervals such that their union is $[a,b]$, and hence we may get countably closed set which are the closues of the open intervals and their union is also $[a,b]$. Am I right?

Comment: @John: In you comment, is $[a,b]$ an _open_ interval or a _closed_ interval?

Comment: Sorry. $[a,b]$ should be $(a,b)$.

Comment: @John: Don't worry about "closures of open intervals," just worry about _closed intervals_: if $(a,b)$ is any open interval, then it is a countable union of (non-degenerate) closed intervals (which happen to be the closures of their interiors, but that is not too important).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start with an open interval.  Can you show it is the union of countably many closed intervals?